# .htaccess if file does not exist?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have a directory like this:

/hop/disk1/0000/1231/file.txt

https://192.168.1.1/hop/disk1/0000/1231/file.txt

But some files does not exist in hop, exist in hop2:

/hop2/disk1/0000/1231/file.txt

How can I redirect request to hop2 if file does not exist in hop?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set up a rewrite rule with 2 preceding conditions:

1. `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` - the request *isn't* for a file that exists
2. `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`  - the request *isn't* for a directory that exists

After that, the rule itself is straightforward - capture the entire filepath after `/hop/` and rewrite the URI so that it begins with `http://192.168.1.1//hop2/` and ends with the same filepath.

```
RewriteRule ^/hop/(.*)$ http://192.168.1.1/hop2/$1 [L]
```

**Putting it all together:**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteRule ^/hop/(.*)$ http://192.168.1.1/hop2/$1 [L]
```